# sqlite3, selects with datetime

Tags: python, sqlite

**The Problem**

I am trying to do a sqlite3 query, in Python, using a datetime in the WHERE section.

The placedDate is datetime object, and my code is below. For some reason, the query returns items placed today, rather than bets placed in the last hour. What could be wrong?

```
    sql = r"""SELECT count(*) FROM bet WHERE placedDate>?"""
    td = timedelta( minutes=60 )
    dt = datetime.utcnow()-td
    with closing( conn.cursor() ) as cur:
        cur.execute( sql, ( dt, ) )
        print cur.fetchone()[0]
```

I have also tried

```
sql = r"""SELECT count(*) FROM bet WHERE placedDate>datetime(?)"""
```

An example placedDate is

```
 'placedDate': u'2015-02-06T01:20:37.000Z',
```

**Table Definition**

Using

```
    meta = conn.execute("PRAGMA table_info('bet')")
    print( 'bet table info:')
    for r in meta:
        print r
```

I get

```
(0, u'id', u'INTEGER', 0, None, 1)
(1, u'marketId', u'varchar', 0, None, 0)
(2, u'sizeMatched', u'decimal(10,2)', 0, None, 0)
(3, u'orderType', u'varchar', 0, None, 0)
(4, u'selectionId', u'int', 0, None, 0)
(5, u'price', u'decimal(5,2)', 0, None, 0)
(6, u'persistenceType', u'varchar', 0, None, 0)
(7, u'size', u'decimal(10,2)', 0, None, 0)
(8, u'placedDate', u'datetime', 0, None, 0)
(9, u'averagePriceMatched', u'decimal(10,2)', 0, None, 0)
(10, u'side', u'varchar', 0, None, 0)
(11, u'description', u'varchar', 0, None, 0)
```

Comment: Please show us the table-definition.

Comment: The table definition does not help because SQLite [uses dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). What is the format of the date values in the table?

Comment: CL - are you saying that I need to convert to datetime before storing the dates? I think I use strings in the insert statement

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 import sqlite3
 from datetime import datetime, timedelta

 conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:", detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)


 c = conn.cursor()

 c.execute("""
 CREATE TABLE test (
    foo varchar,
    ts datetime
 );""")

 rowcount = c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test").fetchone()[0]
 assert 0 == rowcount, rowcount

 dt = timedelta(minutes=5)

 now = datetime.now()

 then = now

 for i in xrange(100):
     then -= dt
     c.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES(?, ?)", (str(i), then))

 rowcount = c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test").fetchone()[0]
 assert 100 == rowcount, rowcount


 hour_ago = now - timedelta(minutes=60)
 rowcount = c.execute(
     "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE ts >= ?",
     (hour_ago,) ).fetchone()[0]
 assert 12 == rowcount, rowcount
```

If it does for you, I suspect the data being different than your expectation.